# Load data from xml

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to load values from an xml into an xsl...
This is my data xml:

```
<root>
<Firma ID_FIRMY="15" ROLE_FIRMY="O" KOD_FIRMY="Tomášov">
</Firma>
</root>
```

This is my xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-xsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<Firma>
  <FirstName><xsl:value-of select="@ROLE_FIRMY" /></FirstName>
</Firma>
</xsl:template>
```

I can not load values from xml. Have you got any ideas? Thanks

i need this output xml:

```
<Main>
<Firma55>
 <ROLE>O</ROLE>
</Firma55>
</Main>
```

Comment: What do you mean by loading data into XSL? XSLT can be used to transform an XML into another XML, text, etc. What is it that you are expecting? Moreover, the XSLT you've written isn't correct. It should be having a template within which do you put for-each..

Comment: i need transform xml structure to other xml structure..but first i need to know how coul i show this values..

Comment: Can you update your question with the expected output?

Comment: `ROLE_FIRMY` is an **attribute**; you access it by `<xsl:value-of select="@ROLE_FIRMY"/>`.

Comment: not run...i updated my first post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some weird issues with your stylesheet:

1. The closing stylesheet tag is missing;
2. The xmlns:xsl namespace is incorrect;
3. The stylesheet version attribute is missing.

Try it this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <Main>
        <xsl:for-each select="root/Firma">    
            <Firma55>
                <ROLE><xsl:value-of select="@ROLE_FIRMY"/></ROLE>
            </Firma55>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Main> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```